# R & xml2: Locate elements by specific text value, store all children values in data.frame

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

I work with regularly refreshed XML reports and I would like to automate the munging process using R & xml2.

[Here's a link to an entire example file.](https://app.box.com/s/8vp5dfmjbu447vkrgo1kt9zmk348xmss)
Here's a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<riDetailEnrolleeReport xmlns="http://vo.edge.fm.cms.hhs.gov">
    <includedFileHeader>
        <outboundFileIdentifier>f2e55625-e70e-4f9d-8278-fc5de7c04d47</outboundFileIdentifier>
        <cmsBatchIdentifier>RIP-2015-00096</cmsBatchIdentifier>
        <cmsJobIdentifier>16220</cmsJobIdentifier>
        <snapShotFileName>25032.BACKUP.D03152016T032051.dat</snapShotFileName>
        <snapShotFileHash>20d887c9a71fa920dbb91edc3d171eb64a784dd6</snapShotFileHash>
        <outboundFileGenerationDateTime>2016-03-15T15:20:54</outboundFileGenerationDateTime>
        <interfaceControlReleaseNumber>04.03.01</interfaceControlReleaseNumber>
        <edgeServerVersion>EDGEServer_14.09_01_b0186</edgeServerVersion>
        <edgeServerProcessIdentifier>8</edgeServerProcessIdentifier>
        <outboundFileTypeCode>RIDE</outboundFileTypeCode>
        <edgeServerIdentifier>2800273</edgeServerIdentifier>
        <issuerIdentifier>25032</issuerIdentifier>
    </includedFileHeader>
    <calendarYear>2015</calendarYear>
    <executionType>P</executionType>
    <includedInsuredMemberIdentifier>
        <insuredMemberIdentifier>ARS001</insuredMemberIdentifier>
        <memberMonths>12.13</memberMonths>
        <totalAllowedClaims>1000.00</totalAllowedClaims>
        <totalPaidClaims>100.00</totalPaidClaims>
        <moopAdjustedPaidClaims>100.00</moopAdjustedPaidClaims>
        <cSRMOOPAdjustment>0.00</cSRMOOPAdjustment>
        <estimatedRIPayment>0.00</estimatedRIPayment>
        <coinsurancePercentPayments>0.00</coinsurancePercentPayments>
        <includedPlanIdentifier>
            <planIdentifier>25032VA013000101</planIdentifier>
            <includedClaimIdentifier>
                <claimIdentifier>CADULT4SM00101</claimIdentifier>
                <claimPaidAmount>100.00</claimPaidAmount>
                <crossYearClaimIndicator>N</crossYearClaimIndicator>
            </includedClaimIdentifier>
        </includedPlanIdentifier>
    </includedInsuredMemberIdentifier>
    <includedInsuredMemberIdentifier>
        <insuredMemberIdentifier>ARS002</insuredMemberIdentifier>
        <memberMonths>9.17</memberMonths>
        <totalAllowedClaims>0.00</totalAllowedClaims>
        <totalPaidClaims>0.00</totalPaidClaims>
        <moopAdjustedPaidClaims>0.00</moopAdjustedPaidClaims>
        <cSRMOOPAdjustment>0.00</cSRMOOPAdjustment>
        <estimatedRIPayment>0.00</estimatedRIPayment>
        <coinsurancePercentPayments>0.00</coinsurancePercentPayments>
        <includedPlanIdentifier>
            <planIdentifier>25032VA013000101</planIdentifier>
            <includedClaimIdentifier>
                <claimIdentifier></claimIdentifier>
                <claimPaidAmount>0</claimPaidAmount>
                <crossYearClaimIndicator>N</crossYearClaimIndicator>
            </includedClaimIdentifier>
        </includedPlanIdentifier>
    </includedInsuredMemberIdentifier>
</riDetailEnrolleeReport>
```

I would like to:

1. Read in the XML into R
2. Locate a specific insuredMemberIdentifier
3. Extract the planIdentifier and all claimIdentifier data associated with the member ID in (2)
4. Store all text and values for insuredMemberIdentifier, planIdentifier, claimIdentifier, and claimPaidAmount in a data.frame with a row for each unique claim ID (member ID to claim ID is a 1 to many)

So far, I have accomplished 1 and I'm in the ballpark on 2:

```
## Step 1 ##
ride <- read_xml("/Users/temp/Desktop/RIDetailEnrolleeReport.xml")

## Step 2 -- assume the insuredMemberIdentifier of interest is 'ARS001' ##
memID <- xml_find_all(ride, "//d1:insuredMemberIdentifier[text()='ARS001']", xml_ns(ride))
```

[I know that I can then use `xml_text()` to extract the text of the element.]

After the code in Step 2 above, I've tried using `xml_parent()` to locate the parent node of the insuredMemberIdentifier, saving that as a variable, and then repeating Step 2 for claim info on that saved variable node.

```
node <- xml_parent(memID)
xml_find_all(node, "//d1:claimIdentifier", xml_ns(ride))
```

But this just results in pulling all claimIdentifiers in the global file.

Any help/information on how to get to step 4, above, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is a classical XPath problem. `/` at the beginning of XPath always means absolute path. Add a `.` to make it relative : `.//d1:claimIdentifier` (can't help with `r` portion of your question)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late response, but for posterity, import data as above using **xml2**, then parse the xml file by ID, as hinted by har07.

```
# output object to collect all claims
res <- data.frame(
    insuredMemberIdentifier = rep(NA, 1), 
    planIdentifier = NA, 
    claimIdentifier = NA, 
    claimPaidAmount = NA)
# vector of ids of interest
ids <- c('ARS001')
# indexing counter
starti <- 1
# loop through all ids
for (ii in seq_along(ids)) {
    # find ii-th id
    ## Step 2 -- assume the insuredMemberIdentifier of interest is 'ARS001' ##
    memID <- xml_find_all(x = ride, 
        xpath = paste0("//d1:insuredMemberIdentifier[text()='", ids[ii], "']"))
    # find node for 
    node <- xml_parent(memID)
    # as har07's comment find claim id within this node
    cid <- xml_find_all(node, ".//d1:claimIdentifier", xml_ns(ride))
    pid <- xml_find_all(node, ".//d1:planIdentifier", xml_ns(ride))
    cpa <- xml_find_all(node, ".//d1:claimPaidAmount", xml_ns(ride))
    # add invalid data handling if necessary
    if (length(cid) != length(cpa)) {
        warning(paste("cid and cpa do not match for", ids[ii]))
        next
    }
    # collect outputs 
    res[seq_along(cid) + starti - 1, ] <- list(
        ids[ii], 
        xml_text(pid),
        xml_text(cid),
        xml_text(cpa))
    # adjust counter to add next id into correct row
    starti <- starti + length(cid)
}
res
#   insuredMemberIdentifier   planIdentifier claimIdentifier claimPaidAmount
# 1                  ARS001 25032VA013000101  CADULT4SM00101          100.00
```